# Options for Filtering Data in real time - Will a rule engine based approach work?

Tags: mobile, architecture, filtering, drools, rule-engine

I'm looking for options/alternative to achieve the following.

I want to connect to several data sources (e.g., Google Places, Flickr, Twitter ...) using their APIs. Once I get some data back I want to apply my "user-defined dynamic filters" (defined at runtime) on the fetched data.

Example Filters

1. Show me only restaurants that have a ratting more than 4 AND have more than 100 ratings.
2. Show all tweets that are X miles from location A and Y miles from location B

Is it possible to use a rule engine (esp. Drools)  to do such filtering ? Does it make sense ?

My proposed architecture is mobile devices connecting to my own server and this server then dispatching requests to the external world and doing all the heavy work (mainly filtering) of data based on user preferences.

Any suggestions/pointers/alternatives would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: From your examples, Apache Solr (search cum NoSQL datastore cum blahbl..) will fit the bill. You can retrieve it all in a short query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Drools Fusion allows you to easily deal with this kind of scenario. Here is a very simple example application that plays around with twitter messages using the twitter4j API:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-contributed-experiments/tree/master/twittercbr

Please note that there is an online and an offline version in that example. To run the online version you need to get access tokens on the twitter home page and configure them in the configuration file:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-contributed-experiments/blob/master/twittercbr/src/main/resources/twitter4j.properties

check the twitter4j documentation for details.

Comment: Drools (since version 5.0 from 2 years ago) is no longer a simple rules engine. Drools is a platform that enables among other things Event-Driven Business Rules (edBRM) and Event-Driven Business Process Management (edBPM). In particular Drools Fusion enables Complex Event Processing. Filtering is just the most basic of the requirements to support event processing, but it is supported. Up to the application what features it will use for its use case.